# Codeigniter says session userdata blank, but exists in db

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Whenever i try check for a value in my userdata column of my session it thinks it's blank, when it's actually in the ci_sessions table serialised.

here's the db content unserialised:

```
array (
  'user_data' => '',
  'edit' => 
  array (
    'image_id' => 'HF',
    'session_id' => '783c15b057bcd9c19d3fd82f367ee55d',
  ),
)
```

here's how im checking for the userdata in my view (note sessions are autoloaded)

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit')) : ?>
```

`enter code here`

and here's how i set the session userdata:

```
            $values = array(
        'image_id' => implode(",",$uploaded_image_ids),
        'session_id' => $this->session->userdata('session_id')
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('edit', $values);
```

Can anyone see the problem? (whole controller here http://pastebin.com/aXeRn1VN)
Also heres my config.php http://pastebin.com/A31nrC1b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View variables are separate from other variables in CI.  I *think* (am still a bit of a CI newbie) that $this->session is not available in Views.  This CI forum post discusses a couple of possible solutions to the problem http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/100587/#508098 - one is to pass the value of 'userdata' from the session into the $data array you pass to the view - which seems the best solution.

Comment: Can you call $this->session->all_userdata() and print the array (maybe using error_log()) you get back - just before loading the view - to see what's in the userdata?

Comment: OK, just a wild guess but it sounds to me as if when CI goes to retrieve the session from the DB, it's not finding a match.  I see in your config file that you have set sess_match_ip to TRUE, when the default is FALSE.  What happens when you set it back to true.  It really sounds like a matching problem, so if that doesn't work, I'd also experiment with setting sess_match_useragent to FALSE too.

Comment: i set 'sess_match_useragent' to false and it worked! but how what i people are on the same ip address, its a bit less secure due to no useragent check

Comment: Could it be that you're using an old version of CI?  The sessions table has only 50 characters for the user_agent field, when I believe the latest CI has a sessions table with 120 characters for the user_agent field.  The pastebin link you gave has a user_agent string of 80 characters, so I wonder if the mis-match problem is arising because the value of the user_agent field is being truncated when it's put into the DB.

Comment: changed the varchar(50) to 120 and it's working now! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 <?php $edit = $this->session->userdata('edit'): if (!empty($edit)) : ?>
```

Comment: Tried that, same result i'm afraid

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata('edit', $values); is it really storing in ci_session table? make sure there is no errors with ci_session